# How To Scale Up An AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

Out of the box, an AWS ALB has a limit of 100 target groups per load balancer.
We have a need to handle more than 100 (approx. 400, but it is a dynamic number not static) and are trying to work out the best approach.

I understand this can potentially be increased by making a request to AWS so this is one option (although I have no idea how much they can increase it by).

Are there any other recommended options?

We use Cloudformation to build our environments and the relationship between load balancers and target groups seems quite fixed and not flexible enough to accommodate a scenario for example where we need to create 4 new target groups, but the load balancer has 98 in place so 2 can go on the existing lb and the other 2 will go on a newly created lb (which would then need new dns records etc etc).

Comment: `To request a quota increase, see Requesting a quota increase in the Service Quotas User Guide. If the quota is not yet available in Service Quotas, use the Elastic Load Balancing limit increase form.` docs says https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html I guess this is the only way to increase your quota as was recommends this

Comment: i've had confirmation from aws tech support that the limit cannot be increased and also that there are no other options other than to create a bespoke mechanism for dealing with this scenario. another option that i can think of is use eks instead  ;-)